# Handling Exception in return by Webservice In Camel Route jboss Fuse

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-camel, jbossfuse

**1**. I'm calling a sample SOAP-WS through camel route I just want to get http status code(response code like 200 OK ) after successful execution from service call and on unsuccessful execution from service call

**2.** I'm calling a sample REST-WS through camel route I just want http status code(response code like 200 OK ) after successful execution from service call and on unsuccessful execution from service call In both the cases our business logic gets triggered.
What I have tried

```
    //Camel-context <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" handleFault="true"> 
    <onException>
    <exception>org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault</exception>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception> 
    <handled><constant>true</constant></handled> 
    <bean ref="exceptionHandlerforWS"/>
    </onException> <route> 

    <from uri="cxf:bean:ToStartRoute"/> 
    <bean ref="InputforWS"/> 
    <to uri="cxf:bean:factorial_WS"/>
    <bean ref="OutputFromWS"/>
    </route> 
    </camelContext> 

    // exceptionHandlerforWS Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
 if(cause.getMessage().contains("404")) { System.out.println("getting 404 from Service"); }
```

**Problem statement:**

> **1.** how exactly we are supposed to get the http status code in success or failure case from web service call? 
>       I tried even System.out.println((Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE)); 
>       but it is printing static string "CamelHTTPResponseCode"
>
> **2.** we want to differentiate successful web service execution and unsuccessful web service execution how exactly we can do it ?
>
> **3.** How can I handle SoapFault in camel Route?

Answer (score 0):

A SOAP fault is not by default an exception. You can enable `handleFault=true` on the `<camelContext ...>` to turn SOAP faults into an exception, which the Camel error handler can detect and handle/react upon.

You can use tracer to see what data the Camel message contains before and after calling the CXF WS which can help you find out what headers etc are returned, you can use to check for success vs unsuccess calls.

http://camel.apache.org/tracer

Comment: Hi Claus, I'm currently trying to handle SoapFaults myself and I can't get it to work. I tried setting handleFault and then using the onException-clause. However, I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when trying to start the bundle. I'm configuring my routes using Blueprint btw. I hope that you would like to expand on your current answer.

Comment: I tried setting 'handleFault=true' and then using the onException-clause and Do try Catch block. But Not getting HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE in case of any response Other than 200 OK.